# How to redirect on apache after running a script through cgi

Tags: apache, redirect

I have an ubuntu machine which I have installed apache on. I want to use a web page to run some simple shell script through cgi and then go back to my home screen. I also want to the go-back step to be automatic. I have set a redirect in my apache.conf which works fine but the script doesn't run at all.

Is there a way to run the script and only then apply the redirect?

Comment:
I think [this](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/109937-how-redirect-web-page-shell-script.html) may be the answer but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your apache redirects accesses to your cgi-script **before** it is executed.

You will need to do the redirection in your cgi-script. There are two possible ways:

1. Output a simple html page with a meta-redirect as in the example you linked. This will tell the browser to load the new site.
2. Let you script output an http redirection header. This will also tell the web-browser to load the new site. Here an example in perl:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/perl
   use CGI;
   my $c = CGI->new();

   print $c->redirect("http://yoursite");
   ```

   If you call this script at the console it will output following:

   ```
   Status: 302 Found
   Location: http://yoursite
   ```

It is easiest to generate this headers with a helper module like the perl CGI module. But you also could just print out the above lines directly.

If you want to call shell scripts from a web page you could also use server side includes or if you use e.g. php call your script from you php page with *system()* or *exec()*.

Some final words of caution: Executing scripts from apache via cgi or system calls in php isn't a very elegant solution for following reasons

- Security: a user may be able to get the script to do stuff you don't want (look for "command injection")
- Performance: your linux system will create a new process with every cgi- or system-call. On a loaded site this may cause a performance desaster.

It is difficult to give more detailed advice without knowing the problem you want to solve. If you want some form of user authentication, the look for the htaccess-mechanism. Otherwise write a php-script which does all the processing when called by the browser which also may redirect to another page whenn finished.

Comment: The idea is to create a browser based remote control for my media machine. I don't know if I'm doing this for fun or to ease me and SO's life (those 5m between us and the computer are so long...). I know about the security risk and this is why the webpage will run on no-travial port and I'll block this port on the router

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just make your cgi script output something like this?

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL=http://www.your-home-page.com/">
```